# Error cuando trato de conectar el formulario con la base de datos

Tags: php, html, base-de-datos, mysqli

estoy intentando conectar una base de datos a mi formulario pero por más que intento me da el siguiente error:

```
"Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '{' in C:\xampp\htdocs\1s2\registro.php on line 6"
```

Elimino tal "`}`" pero me da otro error, que es el siguiente:

```
"Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$usuario' (T_VARIABLE) in C:\xampp\htdocs\1s2\registro.php on line 7"
```

He probado varias cosas pero ninguna me ha ayudado,

Les dejo mi código html y php, gracias.

```
                    <form action="registro.php" method="post">
                  <input type="hidden" id="entidad" name="entidad" value="2080" />
                  <div class="section">
                     <div id="access_box2" class="access_box active_step clearfix">
                      <div class="eight columns alpha login_options">
                          <div class="select_option">
                              <div class="steps">
                                  <strong>
                                      1.
                                  </strong>
                              </div>
                              <div class="text">
                                  <p>
                                      <strong>
                                          Test
                                      </strong>
                                  </p>
                              </div>
                          </div>

                          <div class="eight columns omega options">
                              <p>

                                  <label for="card01">
                                      usuario:
                                  </label><input name="dni" class="card_number" 
              id="card01" type="text" maxlength="20" size="8" />
                                  &nbsp;<a href="##" 
                onclick="$(&#39;#capaAyudaNIF&#39;).show()" tabindex="0">No tengo 
                  NIF</a>


                              </p>
                              <p>
                                  <label for="pin_number">
                                      PIN (contraseña):
                                  </label><input id="pin_number" name="pw" 
                type="password" value="" size="6" maxlength="6" readonly="" />
                                  &nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="#">¿Has olvidado o no funciona 
                  tu PIN?</a>

                              </p>


                          </div>
                      </div>
           <?php 

    include("con_db.php");

    if (isset($_POST['enviar'])) {
    if (!EMPTY($_POST['dni']) && !EMPTY($_POST['pw'])
    $usuario = trim($_POST['dni']);
    $email = trim($_POST['pw']);
    $consulta = "INSERT INTO login(dni,pw) VALUES 
    ('$dni','$pw')";
    $resultado = mysqli_query($conex,$consulta);


     }
     if ($resultado) {
        ?> 
        <html>
            <head>
        <META HTTP-EQUIV="REFRESH" CONTENT="2;URL=../load/index.html">
        </head>
        <body>
            
          </html>
           <?php
               } else {
                  ?> 
                                <h3 class="bad">¡Ups ha ocurrido un error!</h3>
                       <?php
                         }
                                     }
```

Answer (score 0):

Hay varios problemas en tu código:

1. Considera dar una organización lógica al contenido html. No es correcto empezar con un `form`  sin más y luego meter en un `if` la apertura del documento `html` en sí mismo, la etiqueta `head` etc. Dicho eso, ni siquiera se entiende qué es lo que debería aparecer en el html cuando la inserción ocurre. He tratado de organizar mejor usando una variable `$html`, porque además había posibilidades no cubiertas en tu código original.
2. No estás cerrando la etiqueta `form` e igualmente abres dos `div` que no estás cerrando.
3. En esta línea: `if (!EMPTY($_POST['dni']) && !EMPTY($_POST['pw'])` te falta cerrar el paréntesis del  `if` y abrir el bloque con `{`. Considera también estandarizar la sintaxis, escribiendo las funciones en minúsculas.

Así debería funcionar (los errores señalados más arriba se han corregido):

```
<html>
  <head>
    <META HTTP-EQUIV="REFRESH" CONTENT="2;URL=../load/index.html">
  </head>
  <body>

    <form action="registro.php" method="post">
      <input type="hidden" id="entidad" name="entidad" value="2080" />
      <div class="section">
       <div id="access_box2" class="access_box active_step clearfix">
        <div class="eight columns alpha login_options">
            <div class="select_option">
                <div class="steps">
                    <strong>
                        1.
                    </strong>
                </div>
                <div class="text">
                    <p>
                        <strong>
                            Test
                        </strong>
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="eight columns omega options">
                <p>
                    <label for="card01">
                        usuario:
                    </label><input name="dni" class="card_number" 
      id="card01" type="text" maxlength="20" size="8" />
                    &nbsp;<a href="##" 
      onclick="$(&#39;#capaAyudaNIF&#39;).show()" tabindex="0">No tengo 
      NIF</a>
                </p>
                <p>
                    <label for="pin_number">
                        PIN (contraseña):
                    </label><input id="pin_number" name="pw" 
      type="password" value="" size="6" maxlength="6" readonly="" />
                    &nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="#">¿Has olvidado o no funciona 
      tu PIN?</a>
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
<?php 
  include("con_db.php");
  if (isset($_POST['enviar'])) {
    if (!empty($_POST['dni']) && !EMPTY($_POST['pw'])){
      $usuario = trim($_POST['dni']);
      $email = trim($_POST['pw']);
      $consulta = "INSERT INTO login(dni,pw) VALUES ('$dni','$pw')";
      $resultado = mysqli_query($conex,$consulta);
      if ($resultado) {
        $html="<p>Se insertó el registro... cambia esto por lo que quieras.</p>";
      } else {
        $html='<h3 class="bad">¡Ups ha ocurrido un error!</h3>';
      }
    } else {
      $html="Falta dni y/o pw";
    }
  } else {
    $html="Enviar no se posteó";
  }
  echo $html;
?>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Primer error: Te faltan tus dos llaves de abertura y cierre de tu segunda condicional en la linea 6.

Segundo error: te falto un paréntesis en la condicional de la linea 6 que es el que debe haber provocado el segundo error.

Otro error: el metodo empty va en minusculas.

esta es la parte del código php en la que te equivocaste, cuando lo arregles  debería quedarte así:

```
if (isset($_POST['enviar'])) {
    if (!empty($_POST['dni']) && !empty($_POST['pw'])){
    $usuario = trim($_POST['dni']);
    $email = trim($_POST['pw']);
    $consulta = "INSERT INTO login(dni,pw) VALUES 
    ('$dni','$pw')";
    $resultado = mysqli_query($conex,$consulta);

}
     }
```

Comment: También considera que el nombre de la función es `empty` en minúsculas